# Javascript check textarea for specific text

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a text area on a simple website that I would like to check for specific text.  The text that I would like to check for are html tags. It works when I put the tags right next to each other.  I want to make sure that the text area has the tags but with any number of spaces or breaks. Thanks in advance!

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkform ( form )
{
  // see http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/validation.shtml
  // for an explanation of this script and how to use it on your
  // own website

  // ** START **
  if (form.email.value == "<html><head></head><body></body></html>") {
    var node = document.getElementById("grr");
     node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Correct!" + "</p>";
    form.email.focus();
    return false ;
  }
  // ** END **
  return true ;
}
//-->
</script>


</head>

<body>

<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<textarea id="email" type="text" rows="5" columns="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="New text!";
</script>

<div id="grr">Text</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you like put `"<p>" + "Correct!" + "</p>` inside the textarea, as a result it should be appear as it is?

Comment: The `"<p> + "Correct!" + "</p>"` appears below the text area when the text area has the correct html tags in it.  If that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not many good ways to do this. Generally you should parse HTML in the browser and return the HTML string, as that would solve the issue for the most part, but you can't really insert an entire document with `<html>`, `<head>` tags and everything into another element, so you're probably left with a regex solution, something like this

```
function checkform(form) {
    var div   = document.createElement('div'),
        email = document.getElementById('email');

    if (email.value.replace(/\>\s+\</g, '><').trim() == "<html><head></head><body></body></html>") {
           var node = document.getElementById("grr");
           node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Correct!" + "</p>";
           email.focus();
           return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmkQt/1/)

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to check for those values  even with other html tags in between

Comment: @user3272438 - You can't really check for valid HTML as that would require building a parser, which would be a lot of work, but you could check for certain strings, here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/rmkQt/2/

Comment: Is there any way I can do the same thing I did before but to check for additional tags?  Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/8k8vf/

The problem I'm having though is it's not checking for what I'm looking for and not telling me if it's correct or not.  @adeneo